# What is the url format such that when flask receives a post request it uses param.get to extract value

Tags: flask, post, parameters, request, python-requests

The below code is what I already have in flask. I want to know how the url is sending this data for it to perform a get

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def func_name(parameter):
  x = parameter.get("id")
```

I know abc.com/parameter is received and used as parameter variable in flask function. But I don't understand the above format.

Answer (score 0):

```
        basically i searched this and i believe you refer to this syntax to extract named parameter 
        
-- Assume you have a Post request in this example: You could do this 
 You can retrieve query string variables using

        username = request.args.get('username')
```